# Method name ToString()

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

```
GetCached(BLCustomer.GetAll, "GetAll");
```

where `"GetAll"` is session key. 
How can I do something like this?

```
GetCached(BLCustomer.GetAll, BLCustomer.GetAll.ToString());
```

**UPDATE:**

other worlds I wanna to get **the string** `"GetAll"` (not names of customers, but the name of the method) from method name  `BLCustomer.GetAll()`.

I want to use something like this

```
GetCached(BLCustomer.GetSingle, BLCustomer.GetSingle.ToString());
```

instead of

```
GetCached(BLCustomer.GetSingle, "GetSingle");
```

to avoid hardcoding name of methods.

Comment: What type does `GetAll` return?

Comment: What is GetAll in BLCustomer?

Comment: I got the question. Are `BLCustomer.GetSingle` and `BLCustomer.GetAll` static properties?

Comment: what does `?` mean at the top of `UPDATE:`?

Comment: @JohnnyCageWins, it means the sign of the question.

Comment: might also want to see [get-method-name-using-lambda-expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314329/get-method-name-using-lambda-expression)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SIMPLE SOLUTION:** (stolen from leppie below)

Simply remove the second parameter from your `GetCached` method:

```
ReturnType GetCached(Func<T> func)
{
    var name = func.Method.Name;

    // execute func here
}
```

This assumes, that it will be called like this:

```
GetCached(BLCustomer.GetAll);
```

and not like this:

```
GetCached(() => BLCustomer.GetAll());
```

---

**COMPLEX SOLUTION:**

You can do it like this:

```
string GetMethodName(Expression<Func<Func<dynamic>>> methodExpression)
{
    dynamic memberExpression = methodExpression.Body;
    MethodInfo result = memberExpression.Operand.Arguments[2].Value;
    return result.Name;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
GetCached(BLCustomer.GetSingle, GetMethodName(() => BLCustomer.GetSingle));
```

This approach makes two assumptions:

1. The call always needs to look like in the example, i.e. it mustn't have a parameter and the body of the delegate must contain only the method you want the name from and nothing else
2. The method you want the name from must not be of type `void` and must not have any parameters.

You can use this also for non static methods:

```
BLCustomer customer = new BLCustomer();
GetCached(customer.GetSingle, GetMethodName(() => customer.GetSingle));
```

You can even change `GetCached` to the following to cleanup its API:

```
ReturnType GetCached<T>(Expression<Func<Func<T>>> methodExpression)
{
    var name = GetMethodName(methodExpression);
    var func = methodExpression.Compile()();

    // execute func and do stuff
}
```

For this to work, you need to make `GetMethodName` generic instead of using `dynamic`:

```
string GetMethodName<T>(Expression<Func<Func<T>>> methodExpression)
{
    dynamic memberExpression = methodExpression.Body;
    MethodInfo result = memberExpression.Operand.Arguments[2].Value;
    return result.Name;
}
```

And then you can call it like this:

```
GetCached<IEnumerable<Customer>>(() => BLCustomer.GetAll)
GetCached<Customer>(() => BLCustomer.GetSingle)
```

Comment: Your approach is getting closer to what I suggested. I dont think you really need to use `Expression` unless you have closures involved (as per your example). Again, I might be making too many assumptions :)

Comment: @leppie: I didn't know that was possible... You answer should be the accepted one! As currently mine is, I will update my answer to show how to do it the simple way, because I think your answer is a bit short :-)

Comment: Thanks, but I still feel there is too many assumptions to be made here to give an exact answer :)

Comment: @leppie: You are right. But I think we showed him all possibilities now ;-)

Comment: Could you point out the differences between `GetCached(BLCustomer.GetAll);` and `GetCached(() => BLCustomer.GetAll());` I've always thought it's absolutely the same, but it appeared to be not.

Comment: @StuffHappens: It is not the same, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662532/lamba-expression-and-method-group/6662545#6662545).

Answer (score 4):

Change GetCached like this:

```
ReturnType GetCached(SomeFunc f)
{
  var methodname = f.Method.Name;
  // add rest of code
}
```

**Assumptions:**

I guess `GetCached` actually looks like this currently:

```
T GetCached<T>(Func<T> accessor, string name)
{
   ...
}
```

Given the `accessor` is already a delegate, the name can be determined as shown above.

If not, my suggestion will not work.

The above also assumes that `BLCustomer.GetSingle` is a method (instance or static should be ok).

The call would then be:

```
var r = GetCached(BLCustomer.GetSingle); // delegate implicitly created
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I don't understand it. What is `SomeFunc`?

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: Some delegate which was my assumption without the signature of the `GetCached` method.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: Updated my answer, should be clearer now :)