# How to use typeof(object).GetMethod() with lambda parameter

Tags: c#, lambda

How does one use Type.GetMethod() to get a method with lambda parameters?  I'm trying to get the Queryable.Any method for a parameter of something like Func, using this:

```
typeof(Queryable).GetMethod("Any", new Type[]{typeof(Func<ObjType, bool>)})
```

but it keeps returning null.

Comment: Your problem should be related to the Any method being an extension method.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314329/get-method-name-using-lambda-expression and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273941/get-method-name-and-type-using-lambda-expression

Comment: possible duplicate of [get methodinfo from a method reference C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382216/get-methodinfo-from-a-method-reference-c-sharp)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are four things wrong:

- There's no such thing as a "lambda parameter". Lambda expressions are often used to provide *arguments* to methods, but they're converted into delegates or expression trees
- You've missed off the first parameter of `Queryable.Any` - the `IQueryable<T>`
- You're using `Func<ObjType, bool>` which is a delegate type, instead of `Expression<Func<ObjType, bool>>` which is an expression tree type
- You can't get at generic methods in quite that way, unfortunately.

You want:

```
var generic = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
                               .Where(m => m.Name == "Any")
                               .Where(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
                               .Single();
var constructed = generic.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(ObjType));
```

That should get you the relevant `Any` method. It's not clear what you're then going to do with it.

Comment: Thank you, that does get it.  And yes, sorry, it wasn't quite the best worded question.  I'm trying to put together an Expression for a dynamic Any query.  Found out how to here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326321/how-do-i-create-this-expression-tree-in-c#326496  Thanks for the help!